# How to solve "No match for =( TagGroup, RealNumber )" error for UiFrame::getConfiguration()

Tags: types, compiler-errors, dm-script

I have a `UIFrame` with a `getConfiguration()` function which returns a `TagGroup`. But when compiling the script (with the TEM attatched) I get the error `No match for =( TagGroup, RealNumber )` telling me that the returned value of the function is a real number. But as shown in the code below, the `getConfiguration()` function clearly has the return type of a `TagGroup`.

```c
class TestDialog : UIFrame{
    TagGroup getConfiguration(object self){
        TagGroup tg = NewTagGroup();
        return tg;
    }
    
    object init(object self){
        return self;
    }
}

object dialog = alloc(TestDialog).init();

TagGroup config = dialog.getConfiguration();
```

Note that this code compiles well when I try it at home without a microscope attatched. So this probably is caused by a Plugin or any other software. But since this may occurre to other users too and is a super confusing error, I still post this question here.

Comment: It should be added that DM-script code never *compiles*. It's a pure interpreter language. (This is also true if the scripts are stored as packages with .gtk extension) What you likley mean is, that on your home system the *initial syntax check* returns no error and thus the script starts execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem simply **rename the function** to anything else than `getConfiguration()`, e.g. `TestDialogGetConfiguration()`, `TestDialog_getConfiguration()`<del>, `getConfig()`, `getConfigurationValues()`</del><sup>1</sup>, ...

<sup>1</sup>Use class prefixes as @BmyGuest suggests in his comment as this prevents collisions with other classes, also explained in the comment below.

---

I don't know why this bug occurres. There is no `UIFrame::getConfiguration()` function mentioned in the help. And even if there were one, the defined function would overwrite the original function or raise any kind of error that the signatures are not compatible.

---

This is a very confusing behaviour which is unexpected by any programmer and unconsistent with other programming languages and even [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script). Function *names* should not matter at all which makes people not even think about this solution here. This is why I think the problem with its solution should be mentioned on stackoverflow. Even though the solution is extremely simple... If you know it.

Comment: YES. It's generally advicable to give all your script class methods really unique names, best with a short prefix like `XYS_MethodName()` or the like. There is no internal distinction between `script objects` within the language - all are just one big class. As such, any script plugin adding script methods can potentially cause disambiguity issues. A lot of DM's camera code is still using script code, and 'GetConfiguration' is likley used in one of those.

Comment: You don't have this issue with *functions* in scripts, but class methods are an issue here.

Comment: Ahhh. That probably explains why this error occurres. And why it does not occurre in my home system.